# Exemption from chapter

Tags: united-states, virginia, bills

What does an the point #7 in § 46.2-2101 (VIRGINIA ACTS OF ASSEMBLY) exactly mean? Citing from the web ([link here](https://lis.virginia.gov/cgi-bin/legp604.exe?171+ful+HB2016ER)):

> § 46.2-2101. Exemptions from chapter.
>
> The following are exempt from this chapter:
>
> ...
>
> 7. Electric personal delivery devices as defined in § 46.2-100.

The linked text amends "Electric personal delivery device" (EPDD) and few other terms to the Act. Therefore I do not understand WHAT exactly is the EPDD exempted from? For me the statement negates everything about EPDD that was written above which does not really make sense.

It would only make sense to me that EPDD would be exempted from any general clauses in the document except where EPDD is specifically mentioned in the text... Would be nice to have this assumption confirmed by someone else.

Answer (score 3):

The amended section 46.2-2101 is in [Chapter 21](http://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title46.2/chapter21/) of Title 46.2.  Chapter 21 deals with regulation of property carriers (e.g. moving companies).  So the amendment to 46.2-2101 says that EPDDs are exempt from these Chapter 21 regulations.

[46.2-2102](http://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title46.2/chapter21/section46.2-2102/) says, in general, that the Section 21 regulations apply to anyone who gets paid to transport property using motor vehicles.  So without the exemption, there might be confusion as to whether those regulations would apply to someone using an EPDD.  The legislature therefore made it clear that it did not intend those regulations to apply in that case.

Most of the rest of the cited Act amends [Chapter 8](http://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title46.2/chapter8/) of Title 46.2, which deals with traffic laws and regulations.  The amendment to 46.2-2101 does not exempt EPDDs from those regulations; as you say, that would defeat the whole purpose of the law.

Comment: Thanks for your fast and valuable reply. I have two more sub-questions regarding that amendment in case you would like to address them too. 1) EPDDs are be allowed to use "crosswalks". What if a sidewalk ends just at the street (road) edge ([like here](https://goo.gl/Hf5NVt)) but there is no "zebra" (read some "legal" marking) painted to show the crosswalk? Can EPDD go there? 2) EPDDs seem not to be allowed to use the (local) street  themselves in case no sidewalks exist in residential area? Is this true? Thanks in advance for your insights!

Comment: Regarding my sub-question #1: I just found that crossing without crosswalk may actually be allowed: "§ 46.2-908.1:1. Electric personal delivery devices. ... D. No electric personal delivery device shall be operated on a public highway in the Commonwealth, except to the extent necessary to cross an intersection or crosswalk." Can you confirm maybe? Btw, this part D may also answer sub-question #2, but I am not sure if highway also mean local street in residential area, but I am afraid it does.

Comment: Please ask those as new question(s).  I can't answer them myself, and they aren't going to be seen by others if left as comments.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help anyways! I really appreciate it.